# Disabling WiFi inrastructure access in XP

Tags: c#, windows, pinvoke, wifi

I've got an app that needs to disable infrastructure access and then re-enable it (please don't ask why. I'm under NDA and it would be hard to explain why without violating that). I'm doing this with p/Invoke in C#.

To disable it, I'm creating the INTF_ENTRY structure, setting the adapter guid, then setting dwCtlFlags to 0 and calling

```
uint outFlags;
WZCSAPI.INTF_ENTRY intf = new WZCSAPI.INTF_ENTRY();
intf.wszGuid = adapterGuid;
intf.dwCtlFlags = 0;
WZCSetInterface(null, (uint)INTF_FLAGS.INTF_CM_MASK, ref intf, out outFlags)
```

This works beautifully and does exactly what I expect. My XP settings under "Wireless Network Connection Properties/Wireless Networks/Advanced" switches from "Any available network (access point preferred)" to "Computer-to-computer (ad hoc) networks only". This is exactly what I need it to do...

Before doing this, I retrieve the original settings for the CM_MASK.

So, later on, I try the same thing to restore it (in this case, origCMMask = 2):

```
uint outFlags;
WZCSAPI.INTF_ENTRY intf = new WZCSAPI.INTF_ENTRY();
intf.wszGuid = adapterGuid;
intf.dwCtlFlags = origCMMask;
WZCSetInterface(null, (uint)INTF_FLAGS.INTF_CM_MASK, ref intf, out outFlags)
```

But the "Any Available Network" option is not restored in the settings dialog and the HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WZCSVC\Parameters\Interface{guid}\ControlFlags concurs that the CM Mask is NOT set back to 2, but is still set to 0 (actual value is 0x07918000, instead of the normal 0x07818002).

Is there some step I'm missing?

Comment: Hi Pete. Would setting the Registry value manually solve the problem? Sometimes, that works as a viable alternative to p/invoke. Also, you may need to look into resetting your network card. I have not fooled with this stuff in years, though.

Comment: I'm considering that possibility, but this is for a commercial app and write access to that key would require admin access, and I'm not sure that will be acceptable to the client. I'd prefer to do it through the API if possible.

Comment: You mentioned resetting the card. How would I do that programmatically?

Comment: @jp2code: No, setting registry values manually is *never* a viable alternative to P/Invoke. Always call the documented API. Updating the registry manually is not only poorly conceived, it's also not likely to work properly. The registry isn't read each time; Windows caches a lot of this data.

Comment: Pete, give me a minute on resetting the wireless device. I think I did that before for our Windows Mobile devices, but I have not had that code open in a while.

Comment: Rats. I stopped using that in my code. SystemState is defined here (maybe you can use something): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.status.systemstate.aspx

Comment: Here's an easy SO technique to reset the network card: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925768

Comment: I missed the additional comments on here. Not too fond of the UI for that. Kept coming back and just didn't notice that I had to expand for more comments. Thanks so much for your help. I've still had no success with this. I did the IPCONFIG /renew on it, but that doesn't appear to have any effect. I've tried just about everything I can think of and I simply cannot get it to turn infrastructure mode back on, unless I do it manually.

Comment: Does your code need to work on later OS versions?  See the support warning [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706593(v=VS.85).aspx): "The Wireless Zero Configuration programming interface is no longer supported as of Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008".

Comment: My app works with Vista and Win7, but this is functionality specific to XP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with the [WlanSetInterface Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706791%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), if you have Windows XP with SP3, passing `wlan_intf_opcode_bss_type` as the OpCode.

Alternatively, you can also try manually with one of the [NETSH WLAN command line actions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755301%28WS.10%29.aspx), at least to validate the approach.

Comment: I don't know what to say. Simon, you are so absolutely The Man! This has been dogging me for weeks. Thank you so much. Enjoy the bounty!

Answer (score 0):

1. disable the wireless card (you can use devcon.exe)
2. regedit HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WZCSVC\Parameters\Interface{guid}\ControlFlags value
3. enable the wireless card (you can use devcon.exe)